# Determine whether property introspected from UnityEngine.Component would be visible in editor's Inspector pane?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a program (actually, a whole utility suite) to dump the entire object hierarchy of a Unity Scene to XML (for generating project documentation, not persistence or passing objects around). One problem has me completely stumped.

Given a UnityEngine.Component object `componentObject`, I can obtain its fields and properties via introspection:

```
FieldInfo[] fi = componentObject.GetType().GetFields();
PropertyInfo[] pi = componentObject.GetType().GetProperties();
```

The catch is, many of the properties that are returned by GetProperties() aren't actually properties that can be modified in the Inspector pane (for example, some might only displayed when a certain option from a dropdown is selected... and currently, it *isn't* selected, so those options wouldn't be visible).

I'd like to be able to determine whether a given property is one that can be edited via the Inspector pane in the editor, and skip any property that WOULDN'T be shown in the Inspector pane.

So... given:

- an array of PropertyInfo objects,
- obtained from a UnityEngine.Component via introspection,
- associated with an enabled GameObject in the Scene hierarchy,

... how can I determine whether a given property would actually be visible and editable in the inspector pane if the Component's parent GameObject were selected in the Hierarchy list?

Comment: Unity can serialize objects into yaml format, why not do some work to convert them into xml?

Comment: And you may use SerializedObject to get editable properties not by reflection.

Comment: Note that serializable properties may *not necessarily appear* in the Unity inspector as they are a custom data type that Unity doesn't know how to display (because it does not have a custom inspector implementation). Additionally there is the `[HideInInspector]` attribute.